# How to link to documentation from another module/package in xcode docc?

Tags: ios, xcode, docc

I am trying to create articles in my docc in xcode. My project have multiple modules.

For link to article within one module i have doc: markup. But i don`t understand, how link to article from another module.

I am tryed use:

```
 <doc:../../AnotherModule/AnotherModule.docc/Article>
 <doc:../../AnotherModule/AnotherModule.docc/Article.md>
 <doc:../../AnotherModule/AnotherModule/Article>
 <doc:../../AnotherModule/AnotherModule/Article.md>
 <doc:../../AnotherModule/Article>
 <doc:../../AnotherModule/Article.md>
```

But all these things does not work.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the same solution. But after more research it looks currently it's not possible to link documentation from another framework, module, package...

I see in DocC public repo there's an Open Issue: [Support DocC references to symbols defined in another module](https://github.com/apple/swift-docc/issues/208) which makes me think it's currently not possible to have reference outside of your current module, but also makes me hope this feature will be implemented in the "near" future. :)